# Create and run scala code from package in IntelijIDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have the following problem:
Below is the Rational.scala file that has a package name Week_3, which i am trying to import in the scratch.sc file.

But I get an Error: 
Object Rational is not a member of package Week_3
[image: Rational.scala]
Below is the file i am trying to import Rational class.
[image: scratch.scala]
Anyone knows how can i deal with it?

Comment: can you please add a bit more explanation to this part in the question: `refer to it whenever i want from other files in the same base folder`

Comment: In order for the class to be picked up in the scratch file, the project needs to be compiled. Did you do that?